# Can an interface proscribe an object having a specific datatype?

Tags: java, interface

An interface can force a class to override a specific method. Can it also force a class to contain a specific variable? I.e, a class that `implements MortalEntity` must contain `boolean alive`?

Comment: Interfaces define _behaviors_, not implementations of those behaviors, the latter which is left up the implementing class. Java 8 does allow methods in interfaces under certain conditions, but this still is not variable state, just behavior.

Comment: no. the closest you can get is to create methods that imply a boolean variable. like `isAlive()`

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a variable (property) to be attached to an interface, the way to achieve that is by creating an abstract class which implements the said interface and defining the variable in the abstract class itself.

as shown below

```
abstract class implements theInterface {
    public String variable;
}
```

Comment: I see. I was hoping to avoid using an abstract class, though it seems there aren't too many other good options. I'm concerned about readability and maintainability, so I'm trying to keep my code-base pretty compartmentalized.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can achieve almost the same thing by requiring the class to have a getter and setter for what external users of the class could assume to be a `boolean alive` variable.

In code form:

```
public interface MortalEntity {
    boolean isAlive();
    void setIsAlive();
    void setIsNotAlive();
    // alternative setter (less readable IMO)
    // void setIsAlive(boolean isAlive);
}
```

In some sense this is a better option, because you might eventually have a more complex implementation where a single `isAlive` variable is no longer sufficient. Then the requirement to have exact variable would become inconvenient.